# How safe is SELECT FOR UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

Here is my Query:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS taken; 

CREATE TEMPORARY Table taken(
    id int,
    invoice_id int
);

INSERT INTO taken(id, invoice_id)
SELECT id, $invoice_id FROM `licenses` l
WHERE l.`status` = 0 AND `type` = $type
LIMIT $serial_count
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE `licenses` SET `status` = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM taken);
```

If I'm going to face high concurrency is the query above thread-safe? I mean I don't wanna assign records which has already assigned to another one.

Comment: Why you need to create another table for update, can't you just update the table with 1 query?

Comment: @gbalduzzi I need to know what records I have updated.

Comment: How do you quantify 'safe'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `FOR UPDATE` statement, you are locking all selected licenses until you perform an update, so you can be sure that there will not be concurrency problem on those records.

the only problem i can see is that if your query requires a lot of time to perform (how many licenses do you expect to process at every query?) and other queries requires `licenses` (even read queries are locked) on the same time, your system will be slowed down.

Comment: There are not lots of them, just 1 to 5 records and there are not any read on that table.

Comment: In that case the performance overhead will be very low, i think your solution is safe